# JAVA split string by line break + next line start character

Tags: java, string, split

My question is simple, is it possible to use split method or something similar to split a String by the line break and by the first element from the next line? (using JAVA)

For example, I have this as one String:

T|True|25.05.2016 16:21:59
E|1|2|3|3|X|J
L|2|3
L|43|JJJ
E|2|33
H|24343|IADS

I want to split it by line break and E|, so the result should be:

First string:
T|True|25.05.2016 16:21:59

Second string:
E|1|2|3|3|X|J
L|2|3
L|43|JJJ

Third string:
E|2|33
H|24343|IADS

Is there any way to do this?
thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? This should be a couple of fairly simple calls to string.split().

Comment: I have tried this: split("E|"));  and .split("\\r?\\n" + "E|") and all the possible variant

Comment: I really don't get what you want to do. You have one string; and you split that by "newlines"; and get a list of strings, one for each line. Now you don't do further splitting; instead you start to pull together new strings, that are build by concatenating those strings that "belong" together.

Comment: Try: `str.split("(?=\nE\\|)");`. In the resulting array, all the strings that contain `E|` will start with a new line. I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @titus boom! That was exactly what I wanted. Thanks! is it possible to upvote you or something?

Comment: There is no need to upvote me. I'm glad I could help, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know there isn't a split-method available (in the default API's) to split and keep the characters you've said it to split with (in this case `\n` and `E|`). As I understand it: you'd like to keep the `E|`, but you would like to 'dump' the `\n`. To solve the problem, you could write your own method to do this. It could be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "T|True|25.05.2016 16:21:59\n" +
                    "E|1|2|3|3|X|J\n" +
                    "L|2|3\n" +
                    "L|43|JJJ\n" +
                    "E|2|33\n" +
                    "H|24343|IADS";

    String[] stringArray = splitTheString(string, new String[] {"E|", "\n"});
    for(String s : stringArray) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

In the main method you create the string variable and assign the string to it. (`String string = "your string here"`). To keep it uncluttered, I have decided to make a seperate `splitTheString()`-method. It takes two arguments: first the string you'd like to split and second an array containing Strings you would like the string to be split with.

For the method I will be using a `TreeList`. It automatically stores the data in an ordered fashion and it doesn't store duplicates. 
I will also be using an ArrayList. Both can be imported to save some typing (`import java.util.*`), but I didn't do this in this example.

```
public static String[] splitTheString(String string, String[] regex) {
    java.util.TreeSet<Integer> list = new java.util.TreeSet<>();
    list.add(0);
    list.add(string.length());
    int fromIndex;
    int toIndex;
```

OK, I will split the method at some points (like here) to explain what is going on. First, I created a TreeSet object. I will use it to store the index numbers found. We will try to find the index numbers for where the substrings `\n` and `E|` are located. I have added the index number 0 (as we need a starting point; Strings are 0-based, so we start at 0). And also I have added the size of the string (the last index of the string is the size - 1).

```
    for(String s : regex) {
        toIndex = 0;
        while(toIndex >= 0) {
            fromIndex = toIndex + 1;
            toIndex = string.indexOf(s, fromIndex);
            if(toIndex >= 0) list.add(toIndex);
        }
    }
```

SPLIT --> In this next part I have used an enhanced for-loop (or foreach-loop). For every String in the array "regex" we will store the String in a variable called `s`. So first `s` will be `E|` and than it will be `\n`.
In the `for`-loop I have a `while`-loop which will loop until `toIndex` is smaller than zero (hence negative). Why? I am using the Strings `indexOf` method. It will return the index of the String we are searching for (starting from the index you supply with the arguments). If the String can not be found, it will return `-1`. All of these values are stored in the list. (Remember they are automatically in the right order?)

```
    java.util.ArrayList<String> stringList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    while(list.size() > 1) {
        stringList.add(string.substring(list.pollFirst(), list.first()));
        if(stringList.get(count).equals("\n")) stringList.remove(count);
        else count++;
    }
```

SPLIT --> This is where we create an `ArrayList`-object. It will be used to store your strings. So we will use the `add()`-method from the ArrayList to add our substrings to the stringList. To get our substrings we will use the Strings method `substring(fromIndex, toIndex)`. It will return a substring from the fromIndex to the toIndex. The index numbers will be taken from the list (which was a TreeMap). We will use the `pollFirst()`-method (which will remove and return the first value) and the `first()`-method (which will return, but not remove, the first value (and as you have first removed the first value, the new first value will be the original second value... and so on (still following?)).
We will also check if the substring does not equal `\n`.. we don't want a break stored as a separate string value.

```
    String[] stringArray = new String[count];
    count = 0;
    for(String s : stringList) {
        stringArray[count] = s.replace("\n", "");
        count++;
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

All of the substrings have been added to the stringList-object. Now all we have to do is add them to an array (if it is an array you want to use). Before adding them to the array, we remove any "\n" from the strings, so you won't have to be annoyed by breaks you didn't add yourself.

Hope you found this answer helpful. Please comment if anything is unclear or if you have suggestions on how to improve this answer.